# Does anybody know how to work with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to make an a bar chart. So i take a code on the internet, but i have problems that i dont, konw how to fix.

I'm using these code.

```
public class tecAmc extends Fragment {


public tecAmc() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Alterar nome da actionbar
    ((MenuDrawer) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("AMC");


    BarChart chart = (BarChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.chart);

    BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.setDescription("My Chart");
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.invalidate();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tec_amc, container, false);


}

public ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet1.add(v1e1);
    BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet1.add(v1e2);
    BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet1.add(v1e3);
    BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet1.add(v1e4);
    BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet1.add(v1e5);
    BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet1.add(v1e6);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
    valueSet2.add(v2e1);
    BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
    valueSet2.add(v2e2);
    BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
    valueSet2.add(v2e3);
    BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
    valueSet2.add(v2e4);
    BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
    valueSet2.add(v2e5);
    BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
    valueSet2.add(v2e6);

    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
    barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
    barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
    dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
    return dataSets;
}

public ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
    ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
    xAxis.add("JAN");
    xAxis.add("FEB");
    xAxis.add("MAR");
    xAxis.add("APR");
    xAxis.add("MAY");
    xAxis.add("JUN");
    return xAxis;
}

}
```

And i'm have problem in two lines:

> ```
> BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
>
> chart.setDescription("My Chart");
> ```

The problem is:

> *BarData (com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet...) in
>   BarData cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList,
>   java.util.ArrayList)*

Please help me.

Comment: Can you share the `BarDataSet` constructors ?

Comment: This error may occurred due the version issues. Check the Version and also X-axis support of that version. Kindly refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262649/mpandroidchart-why-bardata-constructor-not-work , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214617/cannot-resolve-constructor-bardata

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i add X-axis lables in Mpcharts for barcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194550/how-do-i-add-x-axis-lables-in-mpcharts-for-barcharts)

Comment: I think the code you past is for an old version of MPAndroidChart. A lot of things have changed since the 3.0 version.
You can find a lot of example with all the Chart type here : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing so far of this code.

This is happening because
`BardDataSet` has arguments of type

```
BarDataSet(ArrayList<BarEntry> ,String )
```

and you are doing

```
BarData data = new BarDataSet(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
```

where getXAxisValues has a return type of *`ArrayList<String>`*

**UPDATE:**

You can override a Constructor defined.

```
BarDataSet(ArrayList<String> xAxis,ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets){
//DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: And how can i fix it? @HaamzaAnis

Comment: I dont konw what i need to put inside te bardataset. I'm begineer developer. @HamzaAnis

Comment: @LucasCharles It depends on what you are trying to do and what are your requirements.Accept the answer(Tick mark).