# i cannot resolve constructor in bardata.....!

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to generate bar graph using values in the hashmap .For example key- state ,value-number of cities in the state. But I got error with bardata cannot reslove to bardata(java arrsylist,bardataset)

```
BarChart barChart= (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.graph);

int k=0;
ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> theStates=new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : h.entrySet()) {
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(entry.getValue(), k));
    k++;

    theStates.add(entry.getKey());

    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"CRIME");
BarData theData = new BarData(theStates, barDataSet);//error occurs here
barChart.setData(theData);
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message, and ideally provide a [mcve] instead of just a snippet.

Comment: Also please give details about where this `BarData` class comes from - which package is it in? Have you found the documentation for it and examined the list of constructors? I suspect this question *may* be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262649 but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Are you need groupbar or single bar

Comment: BarData(com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.IBarDatasets..)in BarData cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>   ,  com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet)      is the error occurs over there   Jon Skeet

Comment: i need a single bar Mr. Raj Jun ........and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use XAxis value Formatter to display the labels

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"CRIME");
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet );
    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    graph.setData(data);
```